# @Configuration not automatically loading properties

Tags: java, spring

I have this class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:/opt/server/server.properties")
public class ServerConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }

  //    @Value("${path}")
  private String path;

  public String getPath() {
    return path;
  }

  public void setPath(String path) {
    this.path = path;
  }
```

}

If un-comment the @Value annotation, it works fine.  But I would like for it to do it automatically.  It does it in a Spring-Boot application,  but this is a plain Spring 5 mvc application.

Can this even be done without having to annotate every property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True, in SpringBoot you can use @ConfigurationProperties to avoid using @Value for every field. However, as i know @ConfigurationProperties is only available for SpringBoot (it is a spring boot package).

For more detail : [Spring Boot @ConfigurationProperties example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/)